# Is $\gcd(n, \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor!)$ a solution to the factoring problem?

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization, semiprimes

The [factoring problem](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/what-is-the-factoring-problem.htm):

Factor $n=pq$ given only $n$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $0<p<\sqrt{n}<q<n$

I found that $$\gcd(n, \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor!) = p$$

Would this be considered a solution to the factoring problem? I have only tested it for small semiprimes e.g. $21=3*7$

$$\gcd(21, \lfloor\sqrt{21}\rfloor!)=\gcd(21,24) =3$$
 but see no reason why it wouldn't work for all semiprimes. I know that calculating $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor!$ for large RSA numbers would be a computational nightmare, but just want to know if this "solution" works every time the above conditions are met.

Thanks and Happy $\pi$ Day 2014!

Comment: I changed $gcd(n,\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)$ to $\gcd(n,\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: I don't see why $-\frac12 +ib$ needs to concern itself with prime factoring.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I was interested in prime factoring before I became interested in $\zeta(s)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divisors of $n$ are $1$, $p$, $q$, and $n$.

Because $p\leq \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor<q$, we know that $p|(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)!$ but not $q|(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)!$ (because $q$ is a prime and $(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)!$ is a product of numbers smaller than $q$).

Therefore, $p$ is but $q$ and $n$ aren't divisors of $(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)!$.

Thus, the greatest common divisor of those numbers is $p$.

Answer (score 2):

It works, but consider that producing $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor !$ is no quicker than [trial division o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division)f $n$ by all numbers up to $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor .$

Comment: ...and then taking the gcd makes the whole process require more time than trial division, correct?

Comment: @zerosofthezeta, yes, but the more important point is that, with trial division, you get to quit once you have found a factor, if you were told ahead of time that there were exactly two prime factors. If not so informed, you still get to reduce the bound after finding a factor: you divide out by whatever factor(s) you have already found, work on what remains, which is now smaller; you never need to go above the square root of what remains. If you are interested, there are whole books on nothing but factoring techniques.